# When attempting to teleport a mob to a player I get 'The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format'

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a machine where it teleports a mob with a custom name to a player in a team.

When I activate it it says:

> The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format

The command is: `/tp @e[name=Steve] @a[team=Disgiused]` (By the way I know that disguise is spelled wrong!)

Answer (score 4):

With this command, you are trying to teleport all entities called *Steve* to **all** members of the team *Disgiused*.

This is impossible. You need to define an unique target, not a group. Use `@r` (Random) or `@p` (nearest) instead.

Comment: Would `@a[c=1]` work? It is only one target after all, so I'd assume it works like either `@r` or `@p` (but which one?).

Comment: @MrLemon I never used the `c` argument, so I can't tell. But since there is only one target, I think `@a` might be a little ambiguous.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem AFAIK. When a selector returns multiple targets, it runs the command once for each target. Whatever target you end up at just depends on which command runs last. For example, this happened when I typed `/tp @e`: http://imgur.com/9jgdxmW

Answer (score 1):

With `@a[team=disciused]`, you are trying to teleport the entity to **all** the players in the team, which is, in short, impossible. To teleport this person to a random player that is in the team, you can use this command:

`/tp @e[name=steve] @r[team=disciused]`

Or to teleport them to a specific player (or entity) in the team:

`/tp @e[name=steve] @p[team=disciused, name=playername]`

Answer (score 0):

- You have a named entity
- You have a player you want it teleport-ed to

> /teleport @e[type=(Animal),name=(Name) (player)